# Forms on Slim Fraemwork submits but only shows a blank page

Tags: php, forms, slim

I uploaded   a perfectly  working website ( on localhost) with few forms but now the forms submits but only shows blank pages.
I am not familiar with httaccess I tried many solutions but still having the same problem

Here is the httaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I am using Slim php framwork

Comment: Have you followed instructions in Slim's doc about web server's configuration? http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/web-servers.html

Comment: I've used the config for httaccess from the Slim server doc but still no luck. The form submits and freezes on blank page when I hit the browser back I see the submission message  and user logged in. http://uksecurityjobs.co.uk, by the way

Comment: Turn on PHP error reporting, or check server logs. Since it's public server, it will be better if you check logs.

Comment: Thank you guys. It could be AllowOverride all config as I am getting AllowOverride not allowed here . I contacted my host to add the AllowOverride all.